# How to generate unique hexadecimal string up to specify characters long

Tags: c#, string, random, hex, unique

I want to generate so many random unique hexadecimal value by a method.
I want to specify the character length in the parameter of this method.

```
 public string GenerateUniqueHexadecimal(int length)
 {
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss");
        long l = Convert.ToInt64(date);
        string hex = l.ToString("X2");

        hex = hex.Substring(0, length);
        return hex;
 }
```

Comment: Add some code and sample data to clarify this question

Comment: For given `length`, you have `max = Pow(16, length)` unique values in total; assuming that you want to generate `n < max` values you have 2 possibilities: if `n ~ max` then you can generate all the unique values, shuffle them, and take `n` of them. If `n << max` you can generate values while checking them for being unique with a help of `HashSet<T>`

Comment: Random rand = new Random();
            string output = string.Join("", Enumerable.Range(1, 15).Select(x => (char)rand.Next(0x20, 0x7f)));

Comment: With only hex values :             string[] hex = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" }; 
            Random rand = new Random();
            string output = string.Join("", Enumerable.Range(1, 16).Select(x => hex[rand.Next(0, 16)]));

Comment: Less code :             Random rand = new Random();
            string output = string.Join("", Enumerable.Range(1, 16).Select(x => rand.Next(0, 16).ToString("X")));

Comment: Can you explain why you need a value that's both _random_ and _unique_?  In general, that is impossible.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62920385/815724.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a randomized hex string like this:

```
public class StringRandomizer
{
   public const string StringChars = "0123456789abcdef";

   public string GenerateUniqueHexString(int length)
   {
      Random rand = new Random();
      var charList = StringChars.ToArray();
      string hexString = "";
      
      for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
         int randIndex = rand.Next(0, charList.Length);
         hexString += charList[randIndex];
      }

      return hexString;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two main possibilities: *shuffle* when we create all possible `Pow(16, length)` hexadecimal strings, shuffle and take `count` of them:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static Random s_Generator = new Random();

private static String[] RandomUniqueHexShuffle(int length, int count) {
  return Enumerable
    .Range(0, 1 << (4 * length))
    .OrderBy(i => s_Generator.NextDouble())
    .Take(count)
    .Select(item => item.ToString($"x{length}"))
    .ToArray();
}
```

And direct generation: where we just create string after string checking them for being unique:

```
private static String[] RandomUniqueHexDirect(int length, int count) {
  HashSet<string> used = new HashSet<string>();

  string[] result = new string[count];

  for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; ) {
    string value = string.Concat(Enumerable
      .Range(0, length)
      .Select(j => s_Generator.Next(0, 16).ToString("x")));

    if (used.Add(value)) 
      result[i++] = value;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Which of them should be chosen? For small `length` and large `count` use shuffle, otherwise - direct generation

**Demo:**

```
// unique random hex strings of length 3 (5 of them) 
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, RandomUniqueHexShuffle(3, 5)));
Console.WriteLine();
// unique random hex strings of length 24 (4 of them) 
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, RandomUniqueHexShuffle(24, 4)));
```

**Outcome:** (may *vary* since these are *random* strings)

```
f6b 
106 
baf 
412 
443

b150ab7c723caceccdd6b597 
e3c9a9ab066dcea9ae68031c 
0b2e1b368e17ed1d88c3600e 
33bdf06b109f6b953f5ed2bd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want unique strings then they are not perfectly random -- perfectly random strings may repeat.  So you can use a non-random method instead of a random method.  One possibility is encryption.  Use a block cipher with the right bit size and encrypt the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, ... for as many unique outputs as you need.  Because encryption is one-to-one, you are guaranteed unique outputs as long as the inputs are unique and the key stays the same.  The encrypted numbers will appear random, though they are not.

For 64 bits, 16 hex characters, use DES.  For 128 bits, 32 hex characters, use AES.  For other sizes either use Hasty Pudding cipher, or write a version of the Feistel cipher with the required block size.  That last will not be as secure as DES or AES, though that only matters if you require a high level of security.