# How can I generate a unique identifier that is apparently not progressive

Tags: uniqueidentifier

I need to identify items with a string of characters that is not apparently progressive. What I mean is that if I generate successive identifiers, they *should not* look like:

- 1, 2, 3, 4...
- a, b, c, d...
- k4f, k5f, k6f...

Also, the string should be preferably short and human-readable, ideally something you could easily say on the phone. So, a GUID is not a good candidate; a 6-characters long string with only uppercase consonants and numbers fits.

Finally, the identifier has to be generated and reasonably guaranteed to be unique. GUIDs would be perfect for this, as it is extremely improbable to generate twice the same GUID when working at a reasonable rate. Assume that a "reasonable rate" is about 500 per day. Progressive integers (even in hex form) would work great, but then they'd be evidently progressive.

What algorithm can I choose? I'm open to solutions like using a progressive ID and mangling it so that it doesn't look like it's progressive.

Comment: Depending on how fast you can do a lookup if a key already exists, it might be possible to just generate a random key and check if it has been already used ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate a unique, small, random, and user-friendly key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708/how-can-i-generate-a-unique-small-random-and-user-friendly-key)  See especially [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708/how-can-i-generate-a-unique-small-random-and-user-friendly-key/62920385#62920385) there.

Comment: @PeterO. Yes, I ended up using a method similar to the OP of that question. I'm aware of the issues you described in your answers, and that my requirements are a bit conflicting, but those are my requirements...