# Building a unique ID without collisions

Tags: encryption, encoding, hash, scalability

I'm playing around with system design and have been reading up on url shortener. I realize there are many questions around this topic, but have some specific questions with respect to hashing and the order in which I hash + encode.

---

**Input**: `https://example.com/owjpojwepofjwpoejfpwjepfojpwejfp/wefoijhwioejfiowef/weoifhwoiehjfiowef`

**Output**: `https://example.com/abr4fna`

---

If I run this input through md5 I get the following `9e91e9c2a7ce0f0d11b475d2abfb8593`. Clearly, this exceeds the length that I want, so I could truncate the substring from (0,7]. The problem is, to some degree, I can still have a collision since the prefix of the md5 is not guaranteed to be unique as the amount of urls generated increases within the service.

I do not want to have to check the database if I've already used this ID before as that would increase the amount of reads I'm doing proportional to the number of writes I'm doing. In addition, there could be concurrency issues as I grow the number of application servers doing the hash generation and storage.

I see people mentioning the use of base64 encoding the output hash, but what value does this add after the hash? Is it because I grow the amount of unique combinations by 64^n where n is the length of my hash versus md5 being only 36^n?

Thanks. Just interested in having this discussion.

edit:

As I understand, we purely doing the encoding piece to ensure we do not have transmission failures if the receiving system has issues interpreting binary data from the output hash - so it's used for the pure sake of display.

Comment: For guaranteed uniqueness use encryption.  Unique inputs will give unique outputs, up to the block size.

Comment: Can you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708/how-can-i-generate-a-unique-small-random-and-user-friendly-key/62920385#62920385)?  You should edit the comment with responses to the questions I gave in that answer, as it will help you determine the best way to generate unique IDs for your use case.  For example, is someone allowed to access the resource identified by the unique ID whenever they know the ID?

Comment: Also, I should note that there are ways to deal with scalability to multiple application servers, such as assigning each server a unique code it can use to generate unique IDs with that code without further contacting other servers or a central database.  An example is Twitter's Snowflake service.  See also what I write about [unique random identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers).

Comment: Your argument *I do not want to have to check the database if I've already used this ID before* does not work for me because you will have to read from the database *every time* that shortened URL is used. With reasonable assumptions the expected number of reads before a unique ID is found can be very close to 1.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, you cannot hash a large domain and expect to get a smaller domain without collisions. A hash is useful because it is one-way and would require a computationally infeasible amount of tries to find those collisions. However, with a 7 character output and a large input domain, it will be exceptionally easy to generate collisions even by chance.

You're currently using 7 hexadecimal digits. Each hexadecimal digit represents 4 bits. So you have 28 bits or 2^28 possible values. That's around 256 million possible values. So if you guess long enough you'll get a collision soon enough. With base64 you'd have 6 bits per character instead (2^6 = 64, hence the name). That means that you increase the bit size with 7 * 2 = 14 bits, or around 16 thousand times as much, but you'd still be pretty far from collision free.

Actually, for any cryptographic reassurance when taking in the birthday bound, the 16 byte output of MD5 is about the absolute minimum size of hash you want to avoid collisions. Of course, MD5 hashn't been deprecated for nothing, you'd really want to use SHA-256.